# Saving print output to file using sys module, but block continues to run without stopping

Tags: python, sys

```
import sys
sys.stdout=open("summary2.txt","w+")
print('total genes',Signature_1, len(NameA))
print('up genes',Signature_1,len(upA))
print('down genes',Signature_1,len(downA))
sys.stdout.close()

Signature_1=(input('Name.txt:'))#name of .txt file
upA=[x for x in SigA if float(SigA[x]) > 0]#returns dict keys based on integers values
```

The above script creates a file and saves the subsequent print outputs to that file.  The file is created fine and has all the desired outputs, but the block just keeps running without stopping. I am curious as to what could be the cause for this, and how to correct it. Thank you in advance. Update: The script is creating a loop that appears to be acting recursively, I do  not know why, but trying to use break does not work.

Comment: The code works correctly for me. What do variables Signature_1, NameA, upA, and  downA hold?

Comment: Signature_1=(input('Name.txt:')) just the name of a file;
upA=[x for x in SigA if float(SigA[x]) > 0] returns dict keys based on integers values, the file is created fine and has all the desired outputs, but the block just keeps running

Comment: Killing `sys.stdout` is likely to render Python unusable afterwards.  You either need to restore the original `sys.stdout` afterwards, or just open the file and explicitly `X.write()` or `print(file=X, ...)` to it without changing `stdout`.